# Reduce space between Tabbar and Listtile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: Reduce space between Tabbar and Listtile]

I want to reduce the space between `Tabbar` and `listtile`. I wrote them in two different files so i'll add both the codes. tried adding `padding` but no use.

> main.dart

```
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
        home: DefaultTabController(
          length: 4,
          child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
              SliverAppBar(
                  pinned: true,
                  floating: true,
                  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
                  title: const Text(
                    "WhatsApp",
                    style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.0),
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: colour,
                  actions: [
                    MaterialButton(
                        minWidth: 1.0,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                    MaterialButton(
                        minWidth: 1.0,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.more_vert,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ))
                  ],
                  bottom: const TabBar(
                      dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
                      indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          iconMargin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.0, right: 1.0),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                        ),
                        Tab(child: Text("CHATS")),
                        Tab(child: Text("STATUS")),
                        Tab(child: Text("CALLS"))
                      ]))
            ],
            body: const TabBarView(
                dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
                children: [Camera(), Chats(), Status(), Calls()]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

> chats.dart

```
 class _ChatsState extends State<Chats> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
        child: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text("Person $index"),
                  subtitle: Text("your message is this"),
                  trailing: Text("$hr:$mi $ti"),
                  leading: MaterialButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    height: 1.0,
                    minWidth: 1.0,
                    elevation: 0,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 25.0,
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/images.jfif'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Divider();
            },
            itemCount: 50),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: colour,
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.chat_rounded),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try padding: EdgeInsets.zero inside ListView.separated, not inside ListTile

Comment: I haven't noticed that. Thank You for helping.